# Data migration script INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

I've created following SQL code to migrate our database. The UP query is working fine, but I just can't figure out how to fix the DOWN query. I just want to insert all data that is in the payment_gateway table but must also match the correct reseller_shop.id.

```
// UP
INSERT INTO payment_gateway (`type`, account, keyIn, keyOut, resellerShopId)
SELECT 'paymentGatewayOgone', rs.ogoneAccount, rs.ogoneSignatureIn, rs.ogoneSignatureOut, rs.id
FROM reseller_shop AS rs
WHERE rs.ogoneAccount <> '';

// DOWN
INSERT INTO reseller_shop (ogoneAccount, ogoneSignatureIn, ogoneSignatureOut)
SELECT pg.account, pg.keyIn, pg.keyOut
FROM payment_gateway AS pg
WHERE pg.type = 'paymentGatewayOgone'
AND reseller_shop.id = pg.resellerShopId
```

Comment: what is the problem with the query?

Comment: Basically it is quite strange that you need to reference the table that you are inserting to. If that is required, you should use that table in the `SELECT` statement and `INNER JOIN` payment_gateway and reseller_shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed that I had to use UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO.

```
UPDATE reseller_shop AS rs, payment_gateway AS pg
SET rs.ogoneAccount = pg.account, rs.ogoneSignatureIn = pg.keyIn, rs.ogoneSignatureOut = pg.keyOut
WHERE pg.type = 'paymentGatewayOgone'
AND rs.id = pg.resellerShopId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO reseller_shop (ogoneAccount, ogoneSignatureIn, ogoneSignatureOut)
SELECT pg.account, pg.keyIn, pg.keyOut FROM payment_gateway AS pg 
WHERE pg.type = 'paymentGatewayOgone' AND  pg.resellerShopId in 
(select reseller_shop.id from reseller_shop_id)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this:

```
INSERT INTO reseller_shop (ogoneAccount, ogoneSignatureIn, ogoneSignatureOut)
SELECT pg.account, pg.keyIn, pg.keyOut
FROM payment_gateway AS pg 
    INNER JOIN reseller_shop AS rs ON  rs.id = pg.resellerShopId
WHERE pg.type = 'paymentGatewayOgone'
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO reseller_shop (ogoneAccount, ogoneSignatureIn, ogoneSignatureOut)
SELECT pg.account, pg.keyIn, pg.keyOut
FROM payment_gateway AS pg 
WHERE pg.type = 'paymentGatewayOgone' 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM reseller_shop AS rs 
                WHERE rs.id = pg.resellerShopId)
```